# How to force links sent by email to open in user's browser instead of gmail in-app browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, gmail, mobile-safari

I have a website that is JavaScript-heavy and requires user to record their videos, When I send my emails to my customers the link opens in gmail's in-app browser which you cannot record from, Plus there's many functionalities missing.

How to trigger a popup when user clicks the links in the email to select whatever browser they wants instead of gmail's in-app one? I've seen some people do that I tried and did some research for it but not results.

Comment: Possible duplicate from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586028/how-to-prevent-links-to-open-in-gmails-integrated-mini-browser

Comment: Can you confirm if this is a gmail only issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default a web browsers cannot open a rival's web browser. This would be a security risk. There are hacks which involve the user downloading an add-on or extension. See answer in [stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page)

The popup you're referring to are most likely apps. The user would have to granted permission. (*This I don't have experience with*).

It looks like there is no way to programmatically force emails on Android to open in Chrome browser. The user has to alter their system settings. Therefore, an alternative approach may be to educate the user (about the loss of functionality). This can be done by preforming browser sniffing & displaying an appropriate message at the top of the webpage.

With JavaScript, you can test if a function is supported & enabled by creating functions. Below is an example, which determine is LocalStorage is available. (*It's only for illustration purposes*).

```
function isLocalStorageEnabled(){
    var test = 'test';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(test, test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

if(isLocalStorageEnabled() === true){
    // available
}else{
    // unavailable
}
```

Also I believe there is no single way to detect if the user, is using Gmails built-in browser or Chrome. However based on the following factors, you can assume they're using Gmail if:

- User has clicked an email link. (You can append a query string. On landing on site, store in session and redirect without the append query string).
- User is on android `(/Android/.test(window.navigator.userAgent))`.
- User is on Chrome (see answer [stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618)).
- The web browser doesn't support some sort of JavaScript function, which works on Chrome but not on Gmails browser.

If all criteria are true, then you can then display a message like: `For full functionality, please use Chrome or alternatively in Gmail: Go to Settings, General, and uncheck the option to open links in gmail (and reopen link from Gmail)`.

Note: browser detection can be faked. However this should be fine for displaying messages.

Answer (score 0):

The option to send links in the Gmail (or any app) WebView to the system handler is reserved for the app itself.

The implementation for apps is described here:

[WKWebView open links from certain domain in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231061/wkwebview-open-links-from-certain-domain-in-safari)

[WebView link click open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser)

However, if you instruct the recipient to long press the link in the email, there is an option to open the link in browser and that will take them to the default browser.

Comment: It's a Web App not android.

Comment: Are you not referring to the Gmail App on mobile devices?

On mobile devices, the Mobile App and only the Mobile App has the capability of changing where links are opened. I merely provided links to the evidence of that.